# RobotFramework: XPath exists manually but cannot be found in Robot code

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Not sure why but here is my code

```
Click Link xpath=//*[contains(., "Download certificate")]
```

This works manually but not when i use robot. The page's html/xml code is here

https://pastebin.com/k30GXWj3

Comment: Use `Wait Until Element Is visible`. And the next time, paste  - in SO - only the relevant part of the source.

Comment: evaluate that XPath once, it is taking whole div component.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Click element  xpath=(//*[text()= ' Download certificate'])